# Явное приведение типов

Tags: java

Каким образом работает явное приведение типов то есть например:

```
List coll = new ArrayList();
List coll2 = (LinkedList) coll;
```

Явное приведение типа `ArrayList` к типу `LinkedList` как это происходит? Ясно что `List` является общим интерфейсом для обоих поэтому ссылка может содержать объект типа `ArrayList` или `LinkedList` или какую нибудь другую собственную реализацию...

Объясните пожалуйста каким образом происходит приведение типа ведь объект создается в куче и как потом меняется его тип?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Такое приведение типов не сработает и будет выброшено исключение. `ArrayList` нельзя привести к типу `LinkedList`. Смотрите [дерево подчиненности](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/package-tree.html).

Касательно самой операции приведения типов (или `cast`'а) - исходный объект - тип не меняет, просто меняется ссылка на него.

P.S. Подтекст вопроса в том, что якобы ваш `col1` имеет тип `List`, а раз он имеет тип `List` то можно провести кастинг на `LinkedList`, который также имеет интерфейс `List`. Хитрый у вас интервьюер :)

**Update**

Правила кастинга такие:

**Downcasting** - нисходящее приведение, то есть приведение от предка к потомку предку  подтипу возможно если только исходная переменная является подтипом приводимого типа. Ошибка может возникать runtime или на этапе компиляции. Скажем:

```
Object object;
String s=(String )object; //разрешено, поскольку тип переменной object 
  //может быть String'ом, но это выяснится только в runtime

Double object=new Double(1.0);
String s=(String )object; //ошибка будет на этапе компиляции поскольку тип 
// object известен компилятору и он не приводим к типу String

Object object=new Double(1.0);
Number n=(Number )object; //разрешено, поскольку Double 
// является подтипом Number
```

**Upcasting** - восходящее приведение типов или приведение типов от потомка к предку, разрешено всегда.

Запрещено приведение типов не "лежащих" в одной иерархии (как в случае `Double` и `String` или `LinkedList` и `ArrayList`)

Comment: >> Типы можно приводить друг к другу если только они имеют общих предков.

ArrayList и LinkedList точно имеют общего предка AbstractList, AbstractCollection и конечно же Object. 

Переформулируйте.

Comment: См.    

    public class ColTest {
       public static void main(String... args){
        Coll cl = new Coll();
        cl.setItem(5);
        System.out.println(cl.getItem());
       }}
    class Coll {
       List<Integer> coll;
       public void setItem(Integer item){
        coll = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        coll.add(item);}
       public Integer getItem() {
        return coll.iterator().next();
       }}

Если измените new ArrayList на LinkedList все равно будет работать же...да они оба же имеют одного предка и если ссылка типа предка то объект может быть типом дочерних...

Comment: Спасибо всё ясно)

Comment: Ну не очень верно выразился по-поводу общих предков - согласен. Но из вашего примера ровно ничего не следует. Используются строго методы интерфейса `List` - так что будет работать с любым объектом реализующим интерфейс `List`

Comment: Все ясно Спасибо Вам)когда я им сказал что после создания объекта в куче оператором new у него есть собственный хешкод и если есть два одинаковых хешкода эт не означает что они ссылаются на один и тот же объект тогда задали такой вопрос приведение типов я сказал что тип объекта в куче не может менятся после его создания при помощи каста они сказали удачи вы не прошли собеседование)

Answer (score 2):

*Предыдущий оратор достаточно полно описал нисходящее преобразование, но восходящее (на мой взгляд) требует дополнительных пояснений, так как вопрос очень популярен и интересен.*

> Каким образом работает явное приведение типов

В вашем примере показано восходящее преобразование (**Upcasting**):

```
List coll = new ArrayList();
```

На русский язык переводится так: создай ворону, типа птицы. Создай динамический массив, типа лист.
В большинстве ситуаций восходящее преобразование совершенно [не нужно](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361999/whats-the-need-to-use-upcasting-in-java).
Однако, приведение типов работает на собеседованиях, когда вам дают вопросы на наследование. К примеру, сайт quizful.net вообще содержит в себе множество вопросов на приведение типов. Поэтому разъясню особенности, которые знаю.

Итак, в вышеприведенном примере мы создали объект типа `ArrayList`, а ссылка типа `List`. Запомните аксиомы для этого способа:

**1.** Ссылку можно указать на любого родителя. Даже очень давнего. То есть, можно привести ссылку `coll` даже к типу `Object`. Компилятор пропустит любую ссылку на класс родителя, или родителя-родителя, или родителя-родителя...родителя

**2.** Обращение к полю - всегда идёт возврат поля ссылки, не поля объекта. Если такого поля нет в классе-ссылке будет ошибка компиляции.

```
class A {
    int x = 2; //Поле родителя
}

class B extends A {
    int x = 3; //Поле которое должно перекрыть родительское
    int y = 5; //Поле, которого нет в родительском классе.
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A ab = new B(); //Восходящее преобразование
        System.out.println("Int x = " + ab.x);
    }
}
```

Вернет *Int x =* **2**. Если вы попробуете обратиться к полю объекта:

```
 System.out.println("Int y = " + ab.y); //Ошибка компиляции
```

Ваш компилятор скажет, что вы не правы, так как он по ссылке (`A ab`) не видит такого поля. Всё вышесказанное сохраняет силу, даже если ваши поля пометить модификаторами `static.`

**3.** Обращение к нестатическому методу: в этом случае вернёт метод объекта. Но при обращении к статическому методу - возвращает метод ссылки.

```
class D {
    public void doSome() { //Нестатический метод
        System.out.println("Nonstatic doSome from D");
    }

    public static void Action() { //Статический метод
        System.out.println("static Action from D");
    }
}

public class Okey extends D {
    public void doSome() {
        System.out.println("doSome from Okey");
    }

    public static void Action() {
        System.out.println("static Action from Okey");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        D o = new Okey();
        o.doSome(); //Из класса Okey 
        o.Action(); //Из класса D  
    }
}
```

Вывод:

> Nonstatic doSome from Okey
>
> static Action from D

Разгадка проста, нестатический метод - это метод объекта, статический - метод класса. Когда мы вызываем не статический метод - компилятор понимает так: летай как ворона. Когда мы вызываем статический - буквально, летай как птица.

**4.** Если идёт вызов метода, который описан в классе объекта, но не описан в классе ссылки - пойдёт ошибка компиляции. Потому что, вызов метода происходит по ссылке:

```
class A {}

class B extends A {
    void someMethod() {
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A ab = new B();
        ab.someMethod(); //Ошибка компилляции. 
    }
}
```

Компилятор такой, пойдёт по ссылке попадёт в класс `A` - глядь, а метода `someMethod()` нету! И заругается.

**5.** Конструктор объекта (при создании командой `new`) работает также, как если давать ссылку на свой класс.