# Приведение типов Java

Tags: java

Приведение типов java. В разных источниках пишут восходящее/нисходящее, в других вниз/вверх, в третьих расширяющее/сужающее. Может кто-нибудь объяснить разницу и привести пример.

P.S. в данном случае дано более понятное объяснение

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Явное приведение типов](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/271985/%d0%af%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: нет, никто не может. Этот форум для таких вопросов не предназначен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Рисуя иерархию типов супер-классы располагают вверху, наследующие их - внизу. Таким образом приведение под-класса к супер-классу - это восходящее преобразование или преобразование вверх. Иначе - наоборот.

Восходящее:

```
Car car  = new Kamaz();
```

Нисходящее:

```
Kamaz kamaz = (Kamaz) car;
```

Comment: Тоесть сначала  переменная car будет типа Car или Kamaz? Ведь получается, что car будет ссылаться на Kamaz. Если я правильно понял, то это получится нисходящее?

Comment: Компилятор будет считать, что Car. И без нисходящего преобразования не даст вызвать методы класса Kamaz